# What's the difference between text direction and page rotation adjusted coordinates?

Tags: pdfbox

What's the difference between "page rotation adjusted coordinates" and "text direction adjusted coordinates" as referenced by the TextPosition class? A visual explanation is probably best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFBox text extraction allows easy access to coordinates of a text glyph in those two coordinate systems:

#### Page Rotation Adjusted Coordinates

Each PDF page can have a **Rotate** property, allowed values are 0, 90, 180, and 270. A PDF viewer usually takes the page contents and displays them rotated by that angle. E.g. a landscape page you view may either actually have the landscape format page size or it may actually have the portrait format page size and a **Rotate** value of 90 or 270.

The *page rotation adjusted coordinate system* is the coordinate system considering the page to be rotated according to its **Rotate** value, having the origin in the top left corner of the page with x coordinates increasing rightwards and y coordinates increasing downwards.

#### Text Direction Adjusted Coordinates

Each text glyph can be drawn at an arbitrary angle (by means of the current transformation matrix and the text matrix).

The *text direction adjusted coordinate system* for a given text glyph is the coordinate system considering the page to be rotated (by a multiple of 90°) so that the text glyph is drawn upright or at least (as the glyph may be drawn at an arbitrary angle, not merely by multiples of 90°) as upright as possible, having the origin in the top left corner of the page with x coordinates increasing rightwards and y coordinates increasing downwards.

#### Comparison

Usually text on document pages is arranged so that it eventually (with the page rotation considered) is displayed upright. Thus, usually the coordinates for each glyph in those two coordinate systems will coincide (or at least nearly so - as they are calculated differently, there might be small differences due to `float` inaccuracies).

For text which eventually is not displayed upright (e.g. consider the case of headers of narrow table columns being drawn at a right angle) you might prefer one or the other system, depending on what you try to achieve:

- If you want to compare the position of arbitrary glyphs relative to each other, you obviously need a common coordinate system, so the text direction adjusted coordinates cannot be used; for this case PDFBox chose the page rotation adjusted coordinate system.
- If you want to check if two glyphs with the same text drawing direction are next to each other, i.e. probably forming (a part of) a word, testing their text direction adjusted coordinates may be preferable.

(Actually in my experience neither of those coordinate systems is the one you need for text extraction post processing; often you need the coordinates in the unrotated default PDF page user space coordinate system to e.g. overlay them with some markup annotation. To get them one has to get the translation values from the associated text matrix and then de-normalize them...)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain "get the translation values from the associated text matrix and then de-normalize them" a little further here?