# Which unit of measurement is returned by the PDFBox's getXDirAdj() method

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using the PDFBox to extract the character coordinates from the read PDF. However, I can't identify the unit of measurement of the value returned by the getXDirAdj () and getYDirAdj () methods?

```
@Override
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        String tChar = text.getCharacter();
        System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
                + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
                + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
                + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
                + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335516/1729265 and in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114889/1729265 concerning "text direction adjusted coordinates"

Comment: 1 unit = 1/72 inch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was very useful. Another question arose, how to obtain the rotation of the character read? (example of the posted medium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1 unit = 1/72 inch
2. "how to obtain the rotation of the character read": from the ExtractText.java tool:

   ```
   static int getAngle(TextPosition text)
   {
       Matrix m = text.getTextMatrix().clone();
       m.concatenate(text.getFont().getFontMatrix());
       return (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())));
   }
   ```

Comment: PDFBox can be used to open pdf file without rendering? @Tilman Hausherr

Comment: Sure, if you load it. But I doubt this is related to this question / answer. Please create a new question.